# Huggingface Transformers not getting imported in VS Code

Tags: python, python-import, visual-studio-code, huggingface-transformers

My VS Code Editor for Python is not able to import transformers even though I have done a conda install and giving me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/I323017/Documents/Studies/question_answering_kinnal/src/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import transformers
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from .pipelines import (
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .tokenization_auto import AutoTokenizer
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_auto.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .tokenization_flaubert import FlaubertTokenizer
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_flaubert.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .tokenization_xlm import XLMTokenizer
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_xlm.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sacremoses as sm
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sacremoses\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sacremoses.tokenize import *
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sacremoses\tokenize.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sacremoses.util import is_cjk
  File "C:\Users\I323017\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sacremoses\util.py", line 11, in <module>
    from joblib import Parallel, delayed
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib'
```

May I know the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly suggests:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib'

Try `pip install joblib`

Also make sure you have latest `torch` and `transformers` library installed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an installation issue. If you have already installed transformers using `conda install -c conda-forge transformers`, an additional upgradation from the source using the below resolved my issue.

```
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
cd transformers
pip install .
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Vishnukk has stated, this seems like an installation problem.
HuggingFace has now published `transformers` officially via their own conda channel
Doing `conda install transformers -c huggingface` should then work after removing the old version of `transformers`.